# Can not connect to Heroku's database remotely (Java)

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to connect to my database remotely:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
```

URL is of following format (all XXX values copied from Heroku's website):

```
jdbc:postgresql://XXX:XXX/XXXX?sslmode=require&user=XXX&password=XXXXX
```

I am getting:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "213......, SSL off
```

I had run (it didn't change "SSL off" status):

```
heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=require --app XXXXXX
```

and even added this to the URL as suggested in older posts (althought I didn't see any of it in Heroku's doc):

```
sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are using PG JDBC client 9.4 or higher. Your JDBC connection URL will need to include the URL param:

```
sslmode=require
```

For example:

```
jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<dbname>?sslmode=require&user=<username>&password=<password>
```

For more info see Heroku docs on [Connecting to a database remotely](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#connecting-to-a-database-remotely).

Comment: Updating postgresql .jar file was the solution in my case.

Comment: Since you are THE man to ask about Heroku: why executing `heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=require --app XXXXXX` didn't change "SSL off" status in the error description?

Comment: The PGSSLMODE config var won't be picked up by the database, because it runs in an isolated container. It's also not honored by the JDBC client https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc.